Plastic trim around exterior glass of sliding door worn. Can I replace?
There is a plastic trim around the glass exterior (not the wood trim around that window). This is part of the sliding door. This trim is worn and breaking. Underneath is the side of the glass. Can we replace the plastic trim to avoid moisture between panes?

Maybe,  you will need to find the manufacturer of the door and ask them if the trim is available to be purchased.  Otherwise this is something that is not common to any door, nor can it be purchased at hardware or home supply stores as each manufacture has a bit different design.

Thank you for the quick reply. I appreciate you!

You would have to talk to the manufacturer of the door/window to see if the trim piece is replaceable and available as a spare part. Almost for certain these parts are unique to specific manufacturers & their various product lines.
Almost all multi pane glass windows that I have worked with have the layers actually sealed between the inside edges of the panes as part of the spacer that holds the pane separation. If you are seeing moisture or cloudiness between the panes then this is a result of this seal failing or a break in the glass itself. The plastic trim pieces do not provide sealing in the way you are thinking.

Thank you for the detailed message. Where the trim cracked I can see black fabric like material that is along the edge of the glass panes. Sounds like we’ll need new doors then. Sad because of how pricey.
